# Receiving error when referencing the variable assigned to getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

My html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src = "app.js"></script>

 <title>The Chat App</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="headingWrapper">
     <h1 id = "heading">WELCOME TO THE CHAT APP,<br> WHERE YOU CAN CHAT ONLINE!  </h1>

 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Vanilla js code

```
window.onload = function(){const heading = document.getElementById("heading")};
console.log(heading.value);
```

This code causes this error: app.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: heading is not defined at app.js:6

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try moving your `console.log` line **inside** your `onload` event handler. Outside of that function, `heading` is not defined

Comment: Well I used the onload to declare my get element variables in other projects, and that worked fine, even when referencing those variables later. It seems to be a different issue. I do appreciate the help though.